# Zoom Marketplace: "Any” in OAuth Allow list doesn’t work

Tags: marketplace

I want to use the Zoom application with multiple environments. According to this documentation: https://developers.zoom.us/docs/integrations/oauth/#using-multiple-environments, I should be able to use "any" for this purpose. I added "any" as a subdomain in the redirect URL (https://any.yourapp.com) within the OAuth allow list section of the Zoom application settings. However, when I try to execute the Zoom authorization request with the following parameters:

```
response_type=code,
redirect_uri=https://sub1.yourapp.com,
state=12345
```

I receive the following error: "Invalid redirect: https://sub1.yourapp.com (4,700)". I have tried this for both a test app and the production Zoom app, but the error persists. What am I doing wrong?